# Единозначный парный шифр на js

Tags: javascript, криптография

В единозначном шифре каждому знаку ключа соответствует одна определенная буква. В связи с тем, что ключ должен быть легким для запоминания, чистая форма единозначного шифра совершенно не употребительна. Зато в большом ходу его упрощенная модуляция – парный единозначный шифр.
Представим себе фразу из 17 различных букв, т.е. половины азбуки. Оставшиеся 17 букв подпишем под этой фразой в алфавитном порядке.
Например, ключ:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждая верхняя буква с лежащей под ней нижней составляет пару, в которой одна буква взаимозамещает другую.
Хочу попросить совета. Каким способом лучше осуществить данный шифр на JS? Использовать объекты (ключ - значение), двумерные массивы с парами букв или может есть иные советы по данному поводу?
Буду благодарен любому ответу.
Так же был бы рад некоему алгоритму решения.

Comment: А что? Суперпроизводительность нужна? Какая разница как именно?

Comment: @Leonid может и нужна!

Comment: Данные потоком поступают или готовые массивы обрабатывать надо?

Comment: @Leonid готовые массивы

Comment: Мне кажется быстрее всего с помощью RegExp, вот как именно...

Comment: Для начала сделайте как угодно. И скорее всего это будет достаточно.

Comment: В слове ЖЕЛЕЗНЫЙ должна быть одна Ё, иначе не сходится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во всех вариантах используется возможность передать в метод `replace` вторым параметром функцию, управляющую этими заменами. Она может принимать четыре параметра. Здесь принимается один - `m` - `match` - совпадающий символ. Функция должна возвращать подстроку для замены совпадающего символа. Подстрока берется из объекта `secret` по `key` == `m` или по соответствию двух массивов через индекс.

Подробнее: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

**Как вариант:**

```js
// Получаем полноценные массивы из строк, составляющих алфавит и ряда символов, соответствующих каждой букве этого алфавита
// Для простоты сместил секретные символы на один и все, но можно как угодно
let alphabet = [...'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'];
let shifr = [...'БВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяA'];

let secret = {}; // Объявляем объект, где будем хранить соответствия

// Наполняем объект secret парами ключ: значение (можно и `reduce` использовать, но я с ним не дружу))))    
alphabet.forEach((a,i) => {
  secret[a] = shifr[i];
})



str = 'Железный шприц дома'; // Строка для обработки
// Функция для передачи в качестве второго параметра `String.prototype.replace()`
function howTo(m){
 return secret[m];  // Возвращает значение ключа `m` в объекте `secret`
}
// Ищем все буквы русского алфавита и вызываем функцию `howTo` для каждого случая (флаг `g`)
str = str.replace(/[а-яёА-ЯЁ]/g, howTo); 

console.log(str);
```

**Сокращенный вариант(кроме подготовки secret):**

```js
let alphabet = [...'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'];
let shifr = [...'БВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяA'];

let secret = {};

alphabet.forEach((a,i) => {
  secret[a] = shifr[i];
})


str = 'Железный шприц дома'.replace(/[а-яёА-ЯЁ]/g, m => secret[m]);

console.log(str);
```

**Можно и не формируя объект:**

```js
let alphabet = [...'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'];
let shifr = [...'БВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяA'];

str = 'Железный шприц дома'.replace(/[а-яёА-ЯЁ]/g, m => shifr[alphabet.indexOf(m)]);

console.log(str);
```

**Если вопрос с ключом вызывает сложности:**

```js
let kluch = 'желёзныйшпицъдома';

function encrypt(kluch, str){

  let alphabet = [...'абвгдеёжзиiклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'].filter(s => !kluch.includes(s));
  
  let key = [...kluch, ...alphabet];
  let anti = [...alphabet, ...kluch];
  
  str = str.replace(/[а-яё]/gi, m => anti[key.indexOf(m.toLowerCase())]);
  
  return str;  
}



console.log(encrypt(kluch, 'Не знаю, получится разглядеть?'));
console.log(encrypt(kluch, encrypt(kluch, 'Не знаю, получится разглядеть?'))); // Может так?..
console.log(encrypt(kluch, 'Если: железный шпицъ дома'));
```

Comment: Отличное решение.
Но, к сожалению, принцип не тот. В примере, фраза "Железный шпицъ дома сидит" - выступает как ключ, имея ровно половину символов алфавита, оставшиеся символы алфавита подписывают под символами ключа. Так и формируются пары символов.
Затем, символы входящего сообщение по имеющимся парам заменяются на соответствующие. Так и происходит шифровка/дешифровка

Comment: Ключ можете задавать любой! Это для примера. А на какие буквы будут заменяться в тексте символы не входящие в "железный шприцъ сидит дома"? Берутся в реверсе?

Comment: @Glechik, посмотрите, я правильно понял?...

Comment: Если надо функции передать ключ, а он сформирует внутри эти два массива, то я сделаю и так, только скажите.

Comment: Да, спасибо) остальное я уже сделаю)

Comment: @Glechik сделал, может коряво в начале, можно сократить код, но так лучше видно что делается.

Comment: `...[...kluch]` то же самое что и `...kluch`, есть [`String.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) - нет нужды делать `[...kluch]` можно сразу у `kluch` вызывать

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, сделано. У меня были такие подозрения на счет `...[...kluch]` ))

Answer (score 0):

Для такого лучше использовать объекты:

```
const crypt = {
    'a': 'b',
    'Q': 'S'
    ....
}
```

Затем можно обращаться как к `Object.values()`, так и к `Object.entries()`, что упростит решение данной задачи.

Comment: зачем делать объект, чтобы сразу из него делать массив?

Comment: Для того чтобы иметь нормальную структуру для чтения

Comment: структура чтения в данном случае только от форматирования зависит. Но при этом добавляется лишнее преобразование. А зачем в решении вообще _как Object.values(), так и Object.entries()_?

Comment: Ну да, лучше же создать двумерный массив и тогда вообще будет круто читать.

Comment: А в чем принципиальная разница? :)

Comment: Задавай отдельный вопрос от темы "В чём принципиальная разница? :)", и там уже обсуждай с кем захочешь, только не со мной. Ответ на данный вопрос я дал.

Comment: Ну на самом деле не очень дал, так как непонятно из ответа, как использовать объекты для задачи и чем именно Object.values() и Object.entries() могут что-то упростить.

Comment: Ну на самом деле не ты автор вопроса

Comment: Я и не говорил, что я автор вопроса :)